# When can incremental version number of dependency in sbt be left out?

Tags: scala, sbt

What determines when I can omit the incremental version number of a dependency in sbt?

For dependencies on Scala, I find that I can't omit the incremental number. I need to specify `2.10.3` or `2.10.4` for example, and a mere `2.10` does not work.

For dependencies on [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/), I found that for v2.0 I can specify just `2.0`, but for 2.1 I need to specify `2.1.0`.

Is this determined by the author of the library in some way?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a decision of the author whether to publish a library as e.g. `2.0` or e.g. `2.0.0`. Looks like the authors of ScalaTest changed their decision. The latter form, with all three numbers, is more standard, so good for them.

You can see what version numbers are available by using [The Search Engine for The Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/) (assuming the library in question is available there; nearly all of the most popular libraries are.)

Comment: Is it possible to omit the incremental number and have maven/sbt find the latest on my behalf?  I'd really like to say that I want "2.1.x", and not care any further.

Comment: no (and this would have a serious downside, namely your builds wouldn't be reproducible anymore), but check out https://github.com/rtimush/sbt-updates